# sorting a list of strings using another list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched through stackoverflow but can't find a suitable solution,
I have two list `list_A` and `list_B`.
the strings in `list_A` are of varying length while `list_B` contains the last two or three char in list a that are unique

```
list_A = ['SedimentDB','SeedDB', 'FloorCD', 'QuanCD', 'DewDB', 'AsiaDMS', 'AfriDMS', 'EuroDMS'] 
List_B = ['DMS', 'CD', 'DB']
```

i would like to sort `List_A` based on the order of `List_B`.

the result should be similar to

```
List_A = ['AsiaDMS', 'AfriDMS', 'EuroDMS', 'FloorCD', 'QuanCD', 'SedimentDB','SeedDB', 'DewDB']
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def sortKey(text):
    for i,b in enumerate(List_B):
        if text.endswith(b):
            return i
    return len(List_B)
list_A.sort(key=sortKey)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List_A = ['SedimentDB','SeedDB', 'FloorCD', 'QuanCD', 'DewDB', 'AsiaDMS',
          'AfriDMS', 'EuroDMS']
List_B = ['DMS', 'CD', 'DB']
new_lst = []

for j in List_B:
    for i in range(0,len(List_A)):
        len_i = len(List_A[i]) # length of each word in LIst A
        len_j = len(j) #  length of each word in LIst b
        if List_A[i][len_i-len_j:]  == j :
            new_lst.append(List_A[i])

print(new_lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the shortest (and simplest) solution I could think of -

```
list_A = ['SedimentDB','SeedDB', 'FloorCD', 'QuanCD', 'DewDB', 'AsiaDMS', 'AfriDMS', 'EuroDMS'] 
List_B = ['DMS', 'CD', 'DB']

new_list = [x for y in List_B for x in list_A if y in x]
print (new_list)
```

Output:

```
['AsiaDMS', 'AfriDMS', 'EuroDMS', 'FloorCD', 'QuanCD', 'SedimentDB', 'SeedDB', 'DewDB']
```